# How to have IntelliJ IDEA display a module's name instead of `__init__.py`?

Tags: intellij-idea, module, pycharm

Since it is not very clear at first glance which module's `__init__.py` I currently have opened, is there any way to set up IntelliJ IDEA (and probably the same question for PyCharm) such that it displays the module's name in the tab instead?

Comment: My IntelliJ 14 prepends the package if I open multiple classes with the same name. Which version do you use?

Comment: @sina72 14.0.3. You mean the setting Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs -> "Show directory in editor tabs for non-unique filenames" (which I have checked), but that only works if I have more than one `__init__.py` open, which is not always the case

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I've added a feature request: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000391104-Display-a-module-s-name-instead-of-init-py-by-default

Comment: @LiranFunaro I'm afraid not. Good idea suggesting it directly, I upvoted your feature request

Comment: Thanks. I hope it will get any attention.

Comment: See [Show directory on editor tabs](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111624) IntelliJ IDEA's issue.

Answer (score 4):

Displaying the module name in the Editor Tab is not possible in IntelliJ.

However you can [define a custom scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-colors.html) for each of your modules and assign a **File Color** for it. That color is used for the background of files in the project window and for the background of the Editor Tab. Also when navigating to files, which I find very useful.

1. Go to `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> File Colors`. There and you can create a new scope for each module by pressing `Manage Scope`. Include recursively all files of each module.
2. Then add new local colors for these scopes. The predefined colors look nice; you can also define custom colors. (If you want to share colors with your team, add shared colors instead.)

BTW: I have just adopted this markup for my own project :)

Comment: Sorry, I never seem to have noticed your answer. It's a good suggestion (+1), but not _the_ answer